# Require comments on a base template for starting to create a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am going to attempt develop a jQuery plugin and just wanted to get expert opinion on whether this is a good way to develop jQuery plugins.
I've done a lot of searching and have found many ways on doing jQuery plugins. I am surprised that these isn't a standard approach as most plugins seem to all be used in the same way.
I tried to follow a similar approach to the jQueryUI plugins whereby methods are called on elements by invoking `$('selector').plugin('method1');`

Any comments/critisms on my solution would be useful.

```
(function(plugin, $, undefined) {
    var instances = [];
    var defaultOptions = {
        exampleOpt1: 1,
        exampleOpt2: 2
    };


    var pluginClass = function($element,options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    pluginClass.prototype.method1 = function() {
        console.log(this.options.exampleOpt1);
    }

    pluginClass.prototype.method2 = function(param2) {
        console.log('Hello there '+param2);
    }

    $.fn.plugin = function() {
        if ((arguments.length==0) || $.isPlainObject(arguments[0])) {
            var opts = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, arguments[0]||{});
            this.each(function(index, Element){
                if (typeof $(Element).data('instanceIndex') == 'undefined') {
                    instances.push(new pluginClass($(Element).data('instanceIndex',instances.length),opts));
                } else {
                    $.error('Attempting to initialise the element again.')
                }
            });
        } else {
            if (typeof pluginClass.prototype[arguments[0]] == 'undefined') {
                $.error('Method '+arguments[0]+'() not defined.');
            } else {
                var iArguments = arguments; //arguments disappears in each() callback
                this.each(function(index,Element){
                    if (typeof $(Element).data('instanceIndex') != 'undefined') {
                        instances[$(Element).data('instanceIndex')][iArguments[0]].apply(instances[$(Element).data('instanceIndex')],Array.prototype.slice.call(iArguments,1));
                    } else {
                        $.error('Cannot call method as element has not been initialised yet.');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
}(window.plugin = window.plugin || {}, jQuery ));
```

Comment: It certainly seems a lot more complex than most plugins I have seen. Can you provide an explanation/justification for some of the complexity, perhaps?